# Angular2 app not starting from index.html without node server

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular

I have recently been building an Angular2 starter kit for my own use, using various bits and pieces found in tutorials and SO. I now have gulp tasks to bundle the app for production but it won't work without running it through a server, node in this case.

Here is the repo: https://github.com/LGLabGreg/lg-angular2

Basically running `gulp dist` will bundle the app fine in dist/ folder, but clicking the index.html in that folder doesn't work, the app is stuck on "Loading...". If I serve it with node it works.

Thanks.

Comment: What does your node file (usually app.js OR bin/www) look like? You have to start the node server and navigate to the correct localhost port.

Comment: Thanks Jeremy, it does work with node, but I would like it to work "standalone" by just opening the index.html in a browser or uploading it via ftp.

Answer (score 2):

That's because when you are serving it from node the baseUrl is set correct `/`, but when you just click on `index.html` the baseUrl is set to `/` which will probably be `C:\` (`file://`). Resulting in the browser trying to obtain all resource from `file://`. Check your browser console for errors

Sooooo... that's a pickle

Comment: Thanks Pierre, that was it. Oddly enough I wasn't getting console errors locally which would have been helpful and I didn't actually check the console after I uploaded via ftp. So if uploaded to the root of a server the default base url `/` will work, just needs to be adjusted if the app is in a folder, and use a server locally. I upvoted your answer but I don't have enough rep :(

Comment: @PierreDuc how would I fix it in this scenario?

Comment: Use a web server, or set the base URL to the folder of your index.html location